# Count no. of lines through Hough Transform

Tags: python, opencv

I took an image where there is only a single line, so the output should be `1` but i am getting `24`.

My code:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(
    edges, # Input edge image
    rho=1,
    theta=1 * np.pi / 180, # Angle resolution in radians
    threshold=17, # Min number of votes for valid line
    minLineLength=5, # Min allowed length of line
    maxLineGap=5 # Max allowed gap between line for joining them
)

print(len(lines))
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. I suggest including the sample image (or a link to it) and also the reproducible code. Please feel free to read the https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Anyway, At first, visualize the found lines to see what happened.

Comment: Please post your code in a readable format by using the {} button in the editing window.  Your full code in a minimum reproducible form is required. Post your image or a link to it. What have you done to debug?  Have you looked at the intermediate image in the code prior to that to see that they are correct?  Have you checked sizes?

Comment: I have tried to print the number of line but the answer is wrong. I have a single line in the image but "print(len(lines))" is giving that i have 24 lines....

Comment: Again, what you should do at first is visualizing the result. e.g. draw the found lines on your input image.

Comment: @Sumana Chakraborty. Can you post original image?

Comment: Yes , i can post the original image and detected edge also

Comment: I cannot find your images, if you posted them.  Where are the links to the images?